# Why are there (invalid) defaults for `aws configure`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I created a key. I did aws-configure at the command line using the values from the key *and I used the defaults provided for region and format*:

```
$ aws configure                                                                         
AWS Access Key ID [****************9104]: AKI...                          
AWS Secret Access Key [****************X8QW]: 1BDj...  
Default region name [T4qF8cA0VhFpL+tGcpyXmsWN/Ln3WMkLwpeJBwVhDkd5lBolFNeEG1JBPFsnVXKPCp2
CUZHni/qw]:                                                                             
Default output format [7PLCQ8tqlVx0f8vsKIA/fp5quhDMwhMLgP2Mtd1UHU34lAUYSjJ8p3blRDU4VWb9z
tvJlnAr+UA/]:
```

But now trying to do any `iam` command I get:

```
$ aws iam list-users

Invalid endpoint: https://iam.T4qF8cA0VhFpL+tGcpyXmsWN/Ln3WMkLwpeJBwVhDkd5lBolFNeEG1JBPFsnVXKPCp2CUZHni/qw.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default region name should be the one of region name, not the value you specified,

```
T4qF8cA0VhFpL+tGcpyXmsWN/Ln3WMkLwpeJBwVhDkd5lBolFNeEG1JBPFsnVXKPCp2
CUZHni/qw
```

Please input your region code such as `us-west-1`. The output format is also wrong. Might be `json`. See [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

Comment: Yes `us-east-1` and `json` worked.  Why did aws give me the odd defaults that also did not work.  That is the underlying question and I've updated the question above to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

These are currently set values. So you already configured the CLI earlier by providing incorrect data.

> When you are prompted for information, the current value will be displayed in [brackets]. If the config item has no value, it be displayed as [None].